# Value for Text Input is Undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a vowel counter to try to learn the basics, but for some reason when I use the .value property it returns an undefined. It's not getting the value from what is typed in the input field.

```
<body>
<div class="all">
    <div class="counter">
        <h3>Vowels in your word:</h3>
        <h1 id="number">00</h1>
    </div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="textInput" id="textInput" placeholder="Write here" value="">
    </form>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

```
let textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
let inputArray = textInput.value.split('');
let number = document.getElementById("number");

let vowelCounter = (inputArray) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if(inputArray[i] == "a"
        || inputArray[i] == "i"
        || inputArray[i] == "o"
        || inputArray[i] == "u"
        || inputArray[i] == "e"
        || inputArray[i] == "A"
        || inputArray[i] == "I"
        || inputArray[i] == "O"
        || inputArray[i] == "U"
        || inputArray[i] == "E") {
            number.innerText = parseInt(number.innerText) + 1;
        }
    }
}

vowelCounter(inputArray);
```

Comment: Value should be an empty string and not undefined. It is like that because the script runs right away and the textbox has no value. The code does not run automatically when the value changes, you need to code that. That is why we have event listeners.

Comment: You do not have a trigger point or on-change event written to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the on-change event and move the above three lines inside and call the vowelCounter() method inside as shown below:

```
document.getElementById("textInput").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  let textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
  let inputArray = textInput.value.split('');
  let number = document.getElementById("number");
  console.log(textInput.value);
  console.log(number);
  vowelCounter(inputArray);
});
```

Play with it and other javascript events, and you will surely get the hang of it. Keep Coding!

Comment: i would also add a `toLowerCase()` so the codeline looks like this: `let inputArray = textInput.value.toLowerCase().split('');`. This makes all letters lower Case and makes checking for capital vowels redundant :)